# How to use SUMIF to calculate 12-month moving averages

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

On a single sheet I have Datapoints listed from top to bottom (`A:A`) and months from left to right (`C:AI`). In Column B I have an indicator which is used with `SUMIF` to 'group' certain data points.

Say I have in column A several types of apples.  In Column B, I will have an indicator to indicate column A contains Apples and not any other fruit.

If I need to sum the total number of apples for a month, I would use `SUMIF()` based on the Indicator in B and the month.  I've tested it, and it works like a charm.

Now I need to create a new datapoint to list the calculated 12-month moving average of my total apples for the past 12 months.

I want to use `SUMIF`/`SUMIFS` and dynamically count all data points indicated as containing "Apples": From the current month to 11 months previously.
Something like:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"Appels",[Current Column]:[Current Column - 11])
```

Would REALLY appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The offset function may take care of this logic ... [Current Column]:[Current Column - 11] ... but it can't be nested with the sumif, so I think **DSUM** may provide the easiest solution.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dsum-HP005209069.aspx